# Probability definitions about Cumulative Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have some unclear questions as follows:

Problem 1:

$ X$: is defined as a random variable, so

$F_{X}(x)$: is its CDF.
So what is is the difference between $F_{X}(x)$ vs $F(x)$ ?

Problem 2:

Let $U$~$\mathbf{U}[-1,1]$ (U: uniformly distributed variable) and

let $Z=F_{X}^{-1}(U)$, then $U=F_{X}(Z)$ it is strange if z is a variable of the CDF function.

so what is the meaning of $U=F_{X}(Z)$? (usually, we know $U=F_{X}(x)$ as a CDF of X)

Problem 3:

What is the difference between these definitions?
$F_{X}(x)$ vs $F_{X}(X)$

Comment: When there is only one random variable in question, $F$ is often used for its CDF; otherwise it is typical to use e.g. $F_X$. So in "problem 1" they would be the same, lacking any other context.

Comment: Problem 2 is an application of the inverse probability integral transform. For problem 3, $F_X(X)$ would by definition be $\mathbb P(X\leqslant X)$ which is necessarily equal to $1$.

Comment: CDF is actually  'Cumulative *Distribution* Function'. @Math1000 I think $F_X(X)$ is a random variable in problem 3.